# Checking whether today is within 10 days of a field in database using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, unix-timestamp

I have a database table named `ticket` for storing ticket details. The structure of the table is given below:

[image]

As you can see, the table have a field `generated_on` in which I am storing the date as a UNIX TIMESTAMP. It's used for storing the date on which the ticket was generated. The ticket is valid only for next 10 days.

So whenever a user tries to use the ticket, the system should check whether the current date is within 10 days of the ticket's `generated_on` date. How can I check this in MySQL. I know that we can do it in other ways however, I am trying now by selecting the `generated_on` with the following query:

```
$datequery=$this->db->query("select generated_on from ticket where user_id=$userid and video_id=$videoid and status=0");
```

and then trying to check whether today is within 10 days. But how can check this in a single MySQL query? I am using CodeIgniter framework for my project.

Can anyone help me to find the appropriate query for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add 10 days using MySQLs `DATE_ADD()` function, to do that you must first convert your unix timestamp to a MySQL `datetime` format using `FROM_UNIXTIME()` then compare it against the current time with `NOW()`

The crucial part:

```
DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(generated_on), INTERVAL 10 DAY) > NOW()
```

The full query:

```
$query = "SELECT generated_on FROM ticket WHERE user_id = " . $userid . " AND video_id = " . $videoid . " AND status = 0 AND DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(generated_on), INTERVAL 10 DAY) > NOW()";
```

**UPDATED BASE ON COMMENTS**

Based on the comments, and rounding to whole days, you can use the following:

```
DATE_ADD(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(generated_on) AS DATE), INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()
```

Simply swapping `NOW()` for `CURDATE()` we use a date rather than a datetime, we also `CAST` the datetime we created with `FROM_UNIXTIME`

The full query:

```
$query = "SELECT generated_on FROM ticket WHERE user_id = " . $userid . " AND video_id = " . $videoid . " AND status = 0 AND DATE_ADD(CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(generated_on) AS DATE), INTERVAL 10 DAY) > CURDATE()";
```

Comment: Updated as I had `< NOW()` but it should have been `> NOW()` :)

Comment: This query is not working according to my need. even if I generated the ticket before 10 days, the query doesn't work for today.

Comment: Could you elaborate more? I've test the conditional part of this query with a datebase of mine, using a timestamp field, it works perfectly to get results where the timestamp is upto ten days ago. When you say it does not work for "today" do you mean you need it rounded up to a whole day? If your timestmap was at 12:00 ten days ago and its 12:01 ten days later it would not be included.

Comment: suppose I have generated the ticket on 31st March, then I should be able to use it from that day to 10 days ie, until 9th April..I should not be able to use it before 31st March and after 9th April..

Comment: I see, so you would like it rounding to whole days? If i generated a ticket on 31st March at 12:00 then I would be able to view it until 9th April 23:59?

Comment: and also I am storing date as integer ie, unix timestamp not as timestamp.

Comment: In that case we work with `DATE` not `DATETIME`, see my answer for an updated query

Comment: Did that produce expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You will need the DETE_ADD() function from MySQL.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Your quesry will be something like this:

select generated_on 
 from ticket 
 where user_id=$userid 
   and video_id=$videoid 
   and status=0
   and generated_on <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 10 DAY);

Hope this helps,
Denis

Comment: This query is not working to my condition. If I have generated the ticket before 10 days, I am able to use it now also..

Comment: Hello.
Here is the updated query:
select a.generated_on from ticket as a where a.user_id=$userid and a.video_id=$videoid and a.status=0 and a.generated_on <= DATE_ADD(a.generated_at, INTERVAL 10 DAY);